# can i show RowsPerPage in custom pagination material-ui v4

Tags: reactjs, pagination, datagrid, material-ui

I'm using material-ui DataGrid component and I want the pagination to be like pagination component
[pagination component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3ZuS.png)

not the default table pagination
[table pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAcfj.png)

I used this code from the docs but rows per page disappeared

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import { DataGrid, useGridSlotComponentProps } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { useDemoData } from '@mui/x-data-grid-generator';
import Pagination from '@material-ui/lab/Pagination';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
});

function CustomPagination() {
  const { state, apiRef } = useGridSlotComponentProps();
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Pagination
      className={classes.root}
      color="primary"
      count={state.pagination.pageCount}
      page={state.pagination.page + 1}
      onChange={(event, value) => apiRef.current.setPage(value - 1)}
    />
  );
}

export default function CustomPaginationGrid() {
  const { data } = useDemoData({
    dataSet: 'Commodity',
    rowLength: 100,
    maxColumns: 6,
  });

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        pagination
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
        components={{
          Pagination: CustomPagination,
        }}
        {...data}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Read this: https://mui.com/components/data-grid/components/#pagination

Comment: I read it but, I can't get per page shown in pagination component